# Good Reading on ASP.NET in Network-Load Balancing Environment

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

What are some good web pages to read to become familiar with the ins and outs of creating asp.net web applications in an environment implementing Network-Load Balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use no Session State as this will have to be available on all WFE Servers, or configure it so it will use an out of process provider, like SQL

Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx