# Moving an Asp.net application to a load-balanced environment

Tags: asp.net, load-balancing

I have an application which works well on a single server. My customer now wants to move it to a load-balanced environment. Which things are likely to bite me when doing this?

Currently I know of

- Session state, and
- Machine key.

Both of these are described [here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-(aspnet_state).aspx), for example, so I'm looking for things additional to this.

These [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454897/good-reading-on-asp-net-in-network-load-balancing-environment) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632546/problem-created-by-load-balancing-in-asp-net), but the first addresses load balancing in general, and I'm looking for a migration guide, and the second addresses a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing that you might experience is an **increased load on your database server**. If you implement any serverside caching of data, you will be used to your site hitting the database once for a given dataset, caching the data and then not going to the database again until the cache times out. This is a good strategy for commonly accessed data.

In a load-balanced environment, subsequent requests might go to different servers and the database will be hit twice for the same data. Or more if you have more than 2 servers. This is not bad in itself, but you would be well advised to keep an eye on it. If the database is queueing, the benefits of running a webfarm might be negated. As always, benchmark, profile and run tests.

One way around this is to have sticky-sessions. This is a router-based approach. once a user session is established, all requests from that user are routed to the same server. This has its draw backs, most notably, a potential decrease in the efficiency of the load-balancing, not to mention the problems when you lose a server. Furthermore, it will only help when you are caching mostly user-specific data, such as paged search results, which are only cached for a short time.

Another solution is to have a distributed, in memory cache, such as memcached, Velocity or NCache. There are others as well, but these are the ones that I have worked with.

Another thing to look out for, which is unrelated to the above is: **How you deal with file uploads from your users.** Many sites allow files to be uploaded by users. If such files have not previously been saved to a central store, such as a database or a common file share, they will need to be.